# AngularJs: Best way to output nested JSON

Tags: angularjs

I have data in the following format in my angular app:

```
"lists":
    {
        "list1":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ],
        "list2":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
    }
```

I usually use ng-repeat to loop over data and output but because this data is nested I'm not sure what the best approach is to output it. I want the following markup structure to be created:

```
<div>
  <h2>list1</h2>
  <ul>
     <li data-id="1001">Regular<li>
      <!-- more list items here -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.data = {
 "lists":
    {
        "list1":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ],
        "list2":
            [
                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
    }
}
```

IN html

```
<div ng-repeat ="(key,lists) in data.lists">
  <h2>{{key}}</h2>
    <ul>
         <li  ng-repeat="val in lists track by val.id" data-id="{{val.id}}">{{val.type}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**PlUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J0BXLJe9JQnZMCto1Sik?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQThUyJ9S2Cdv3VVENPU?p=preview)

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.lists">
  {{key}}
  <div ng-repeat="subList in value">
      {{subList.id}} {{subList.type}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.data = {
      "lists":
      {
          "list1":
           [
                 { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                 { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                 { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                 { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
           ],
           "list2":
            [
                 { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                 { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                 { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                 { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
            ]
      }
}
```